# how to plot this curve against the original function?

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

```
Clear["Global`*"]

pts = {{1, 0}, {2, -1 + 2/E}, {3, -1 + 3/E^2}, {4, -1 + 4/E^3}};

p[x_] = a (x^3) + b (x^2) + c (x) + d;

print["p[x]=", p[x]];

eq1 = p[1] == 0;

eq2 = p[2] == -1 + 2/E;

eq3 = p[3] == -1 + 3/E^2;

eq4 = p[4] == -1 + 4/E^3;

eqns = {eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4};

vars = {a, b, c, d};

solset = Solve[eqns, vars];

Print[TableForm[eqns]];

Print["Solve and get"];

Print[solset];

p[x];

ReplaceAll[p[x],solset[[1]]]; (*Note this is solset subscript [[1]] but I didnt know how to write it onto here*)

p3[x_]=ReplaceAll[p[x],solset[[1]]];(*Note this is solset subscript [[1]] but I didnt know how to write it onto here, it is also p subscript 3*)

Needs["Graphics`Colors`"];

dots = ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> {Red, 
PointSize[0.02]}, 

 DisplayFunction -> Identity]
gr = Plot[[p3][x], {x, 1.0, 10.0}, PlotStyle -> Blue, DisplayFunction -> Identity]; (Note it is also p subscript 3)

graph1 = Show[gr, dots, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-10, 3}}, 
  Ticks -> {Range[0, 3, 1], Range[0, 3, 1]}, 
  DisplayFunction -> $DisplayFunction]
```

I am getting an error and the need function as well as there being an issue with posting my curve against the original functions curve. For now, I do see the curve plotted using the show function above but when I try to add the function before the beziur curve, it messes up.

Comment: `[p3][x]` is invalid syntax. Try `p3[x]`.

Comment: yes I changed that but I get two errors: 1.Get: Cannot open Graphics`Colors`. and 2. Needs:Context Graphics`Colors` was not created when Needs was evaluated. It only prints out my Beziur curve

Comment: There is no need to load GraphicsColors or specify DisplayFunction.

Comment: took them out! I tried adding p[x] to my gr then showing that graph which just gave me what I already had. I then tried to put p[x] next to gr  like this {p[x],gr,....} and got the error: graphs cant be combined

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
Clear["Global`*"]

pts = {{1, 0}, {2, -1 + 2/E}, {3, -1 + 3/E^2}, {4, -1 + 4/E^3}};
p[x_] := a (x^3) + b (x^2) + c (x) + d;
eq1 = p[1] == 0;
eq2 = p[2] == -1 + 2/E;
eq3 = p[3] == -1 + 3/E^2;
eq4 = p[4] == -1 + 4/E^3;
eqns = {eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4};
vars = {a, b, c, d};
solset = Solve[eqns, vars];
dots = ListPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.02]}];
gr = Plot[p[x] /. solset, {x, 1.0, 10.0}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
graph1 = Show[gr, dots, GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> LightGray]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Are you using very old version of Mathematica? Because you using very old commands there. The above is done on 11.3.

Also notice that show takes default options from the first graphics in its input. If you want the options taken from the second plot, you can change the order, or provide explicit options in `Show` itself

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

pts = {{1, 0}, {2, -1 + 2/E}, {3, -1 + 3/E^2}, {4, -1 + 4/E^3}};

p[x_] = a (x^3) + b (x^2) + c (x) + d;
```

Note that `Print` is seldom required

```
Column[StringForm["p(`1`) = `2`", ##] & @@@ pts] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
(eqns = p[#[[1]]] == #[[2]] & /@ pts) // Column // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

```
vars = Variables[Level[eqns, {-1}]];
```

Solve and get

```
(solset = Solve[eqns, vars][[1]]) // Column // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Verifying the solution,

```
And @@ (eqns /. solset)

(* True *)

StringForm["p(x) = ``", p[x] /. solset] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

or

```
StringForm["p(x) = ``", p[x] /. solset // Simplify] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

The exact roots of `p[x]` are

```
(roots = Solve[p[x] == 0 /. solset, x] // SortBy[#, N] & // 
     FullSimplify) // Grid[#, Alignment -> Left] & // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

The approximate numeric values of the roots are

```
roots // N // Grid[#, Alignment -> Left] &
```

[image]

```
Plot[p[x] /. solset, {x, -0.5, 6.2},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[pts]}]
```

[image]